# How to get a folder size in nodejs with excluding certain paths with glob pattern?

Tags: node.js, directory, size, fs, filesize

I want to calculate the total archive file size before archiving to show a progress bar.
I have some folder which are exluded from zipping with are defined with a glob pattern.
How can you get a folder size with a glob filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of above answer this is the solution

```
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');

function getFolderSizeByGlob(folder, { ignorePattern: array }) {
    const filePaths = glob.sync('**', { // "**" means you search on the whole folder
        cwd: folder, // folder path 
        ignore: array, // array of glob pattern strings
        absolute: true, // you have to set glob to return absolute path not only file names
    });
    let totalSize = 0;
    filePaths.forEach((file) => {
        console.log('file', file);
        const stat = fs.statSync(file);
        totalSize += stat.size;
    });
    return totalSize;
}
```

Comment: that's great! Go ahead and accept your own answer - it's the right one! Glad to have helped a tiny bit :o)

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can't use regular expressions; you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob and loop through the files that match your glob pattern, and get the size of each. Something roughly like (i haven't tested this code):

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const glob = require('glob')

let totalSize = 0 // bytes
 
// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  files.forEach(f => {
    totalSize += fs.statSync(f)
  })
})
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct I answered the question with the correct solution.